# c# WordprocessingDocument replace text

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

Hola estoy trabajando con WordprocessingDocument para poder reemplazar los campos que aparecen en un Word como **##USUARIO##** y que me genere un documento en base a una plantilla.

```
using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(dg.FileName, false, new OpenSettings()
                    {
                    }))
                    {
                        foreach (DocumentVariables docVars in doc.MainDocumentPart.DocumentSettingsPart.Settings.Descendants<DocumentVariables>().ToList())
                            foreach (DocumentVariable docVar in docVars)
                            {
                                Add(sb, docVar.Val);
                            }

                        foreach (HeaderPart docVars in doc.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts)
                        {
                            foreach (Paragraph var in docVars.RootElement.Descendants<Paragraph>().ToList())
                                //foreach (Run varRun in var.Descendants<Run>())
                                //    foreach (Text varText in var.Descendants<Text>())
                                //        Add(sb, varText.Text);
                                Add(sb, var.InnerText);
                        }

                        foreach (Paragraph var in doc.MainDocumentPart.RootElement.Descendants<Paragraph>().ToList())
                            //foreach (Run varRun in var.Descendants<Run>())
                            //    foreach (Text varText in var.Descendants<Text>())
                            //          Add(sb, varText.Text);
                            Add(sb, var.InnerText);
                    }
```

La pregunta viene ahora, si busco en los campos InnerText, todo funciona perfectamente (pero esa propiedad no se puede modificar) ahi leo perfectamente los "tags".

En cambio si quiero reemplazarlos, ya tengo que usar el código que tengo comentado (usar la propiedad Text de los Text) , pero ahi en ocasiones el Word me parte la cadena y no encuentro **##USER##** sino que aveces encuentro **##** y en el siguiente nodo **USER##** , lo que me rompe por completo los reemplazos.

¿Cómo podría evitar esto, mediante Word o mediante código?

*Nota: la función Add solo me va añadiendo a una lista los textos encontrados*

Comment: Imagino que trabajas con OpenXML SDK

Comment: Si. Ya he encontrado una solución en este post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20629050/how-to-find-exact-word-from-word-document-using-open-xml-in-c thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondido en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20629050/how-to-find-exact-word-from-word-document-using-open-xml-in-c

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using OpenXmlPowerTools;
using System.IO;

namespace SearchAndReplace
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open("Test01.docx", true))
                TextReplacer.SearchAndReplace(wordDoc:doc, search:"the", replace:"this", matchCase:false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sería bueno que indicases que esta solución necesita una libreria externa y el enlace a la misma :)

Answer (score -2):

Te pongo un método para reemplazar texto usando `WordprocessingDocument`

```
public static void Reemplazar(string document,string cadenaARemplazar, string cadenaReemplazo)
{
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
    {
        string docText = null;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
        {
            docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        docText = docText.Replace(cadenaARemplazar, cadenaReemplazo);

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
        {
            sw.Write(docText);
        }
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
Reemplazar(pathDelArchivo,"##USUARIO##","Pepito");
```

Comment: De esa forma no arreglas el problema por que trabajas sobre el xml. Que está separado

Comment: @FernandoDiazToledano yo diría que si funcionaría correctamente ya que tienes todo el documento en un string, aunque no tengo ningun caso en el que pudiera estar separado para probarlo...

Comment: Solo funciona si está junto del mismo tag del xml. Como ya te dije. Le abres en raw

Comment: Ok. Aunque no entiendo por que un texto que está todo junto puede estar en diferentes tags. Pero si tu lo dices,asi debe ser :)

Comment: Yo tampoco lo entiendo... pero word lo hace así :(

Comment: Cosas de microsoft. Lo curioso es que acabo de buscar y [ellos mismos dicen de hacerlo asi](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb508261.aspx)

Comment: Pues su solución no es válida, con guardarte un doc con palabras tipo ##USER## ##CAMPO_EXTRA## y demás, verás q si abres el xml , algunas se parten